# Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0)

Tags: react-native, axios, unhandled-promise-rejection

I've been having this problem for over a month now, this error occurs whenever I try to login to my react-native app using a mobile device.

This is the error
[image]

And this is the code to login in my react native app
[image]

Comment: tell me you are not using `localhost:5000`, if you are using `localhost` then it's very obvious it will fail. You should be a network accessible backend.

Comment: No, I'm using my ip address 'ipaddress:5000'.

Comment: what happen when you try to access the local server via the browser? is it reachable? Long answer short, your app simply cannot connect to your local server.

Comment: yes it can access the server in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

There's this part of the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network) you need to take note of. What you are missing is adding an **App Transport Security exception**, since you are not using `localhost` as server, and https is required.

> By default, iOS will block any request that's not encrypted using SSL.
> If you need to fetch from a cleartext URL (one that begins with http)
> you will first need to add [an App Transport Security exception](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#test-your-integration). If you
> know ahead of time what domains you will need access to, it is more
> secure to add exceptions only for those domains; if the domains are
> not known until runtime you can [disable ATS completely](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#app-transport-security). Note however
> that from January 2017, Apple's App Store review will require
> reasonable justification for disabling ATS. See Apple's documentation
> for more information.

An example of ATS is as follows, in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <false/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>example.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

For android, similarly from docs

> On Android, as of API Level 28, clear text traffic is also blocked by
> default. This behaviour can be overridden by setting
> android:usesCleartextTraffic in the app manifest file.

You can refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some api that is hosted on some server. It must have https because in latest devices http request is forbidden.

Comment: It's currently hosted on a local server

Comment: Check your router IP and add that one like http://192.168.***

Comment: I'm currently using the ip address 'ipaddress:5000'